# meaning of 'eat your way to health'

Tags: idioms

I read the phrase 'you should be able to eat your way to a healthy hearth' and I don't get the meaning of this. What is the meaning of 'eat your way to health'?

Comment: Please carefully copy the text. Make sure the title and the body of the post match and provide the source of the text, with a link if possible. Also, try to include your own understanding or research. See [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/36187) and [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) for tips and examples.

Comment: Healthy hearth, or healthy heart? As @Em. said, the details matter.

Comment: 'eat your way to a healthy heart' vs 'eat your way to a healthy home' end up meaning roughly the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a typo in your quote. I have fixed it here, but it does not matter for the phrase that interests you.

> You should be able to eat your way to a healthy heart.

This sentence means that you should be able to attain a healthy heart by making certain dietary choices. In other words, your destination is a healthy heart, and you should be able to make your way there by eating.

"**Verb** your way to **destination or goal**" is a common idiom. "Laugh your way to a healthy marriage." "Smile your way to success." Etc.